# How do I increase the size of the flowfile in apache nif?

Tags: apache-nifi

I prepared a template consisting of consumekafka and a script with my pre-process steps by listening from consumekafka in apache nif. but the data I send is around 8KB. but apache nifi takes it up to 4KB in itself. the rest does not pass to other processes. What should I do in this situation ?

[consume kafka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVacB.png)

[Data's Size max 4KB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVksX.png)

[Data's Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvieG.png)

[last place of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwvvN.png)

As seen in the last photo, the end of the data is missing, not all

my main purpose is to take them and make pre process steps in execute script

[Execute script command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Murpo.png)

But thats error

[The error I get because it is max 4 kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8nAv.png)